# "Reset" random in class

Tags: c#, random

So the task was to make a program that selects three different chest pieces (color + piece) using Enums. I made one instance of a Random object but of course this gives the same number throughout the execution of the code since I only initialized one int holding the random number.

Now my question is, is there any way you can reset it (update/modify the seed) or something like this during the execution so I don't have to create x amounts of int (in my case) to hold the random numbers?

For example: Every time my int chestpiece is used it would reinstate itself.

Is this possible or do I have to create several chesspiece int's (in my case) in order to fix this.

```
        private static void Main()
    {
        int chesspiece = Rand.Next(1, sizeof (EnumChestPiece) + 1);
        int color = Rand.Next(1, sizeof (EnumColor) + 1);

        EnumChestPiece firstPiece = (EnumChestPiece) chesspiece;
        EnumChestPiece secondPiece = (EnumChestPiece) chesspiece;
        EnumChestPiece thirdPiece = (EnumChestPiece) chesspiece;

        EnumColor firstColor = (EnumColor) color;
        EnumColor secondColor = (EnumColor) color;
        EnumColor thirdColor = (EnumColor) color;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", firstColor, firstPiece);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", secondColor, secondPiece);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", thirdColor, thirdPiece);
    }

    private enum EnumChestPiece
    {
        Pawn,
        Knight,
        Bishop,
        Rook,
        King,
        Queen
    }

    private enum EnumColor
    {
        Black,
        White
    }
```

Comment: Side note, `sizeof` is not what you want for Enum; that will give you the number of _bytes_ for the type, not the number of items in the enum.

Comment: @Jacob oh indeed your absolutely right about that! Is there a built-in function to check the contents of an Enum? Thanks!

Comment: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foo)).Length` will work in your case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You do know it is "Chess", not "Chest"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the same seed, you are only *calling* the `Next` function once, which means you obviously reuse the same stored off variable. To get a different number, you need to reinvoke `Next`.

One way to get around tediously creating variables and writing the same call to `Next` each time would be to store it off as a *delegate* instead:

```
Func<int> chesspiece = (() => 
      Rand.Next(1, Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumChessPiece)).Length; + 1));
//Or even, credit to @Jacob
Func<EnumChessPiece> chesspiece = (() => 
     (EnumChestPiece)Rand.Next(1, Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumChessPiece)).Length + 1));
```

Now you can call it each time you need a random number, like so:

```
//Notice that I'm invoking the delegate
EnumChestPiece firstPiece = (EnumChestPiece) chesspiece();
//Or in @Jacob's variant
EnumChestPiece firstPiece = chesspiece();
```

You could of course do this with a named method just as easily, but this syntax closely resembles what it looks like you were going for.

Comment: Or better yet, move the cast into the delegate, with `var getRandomChessPiece = () => (EnumChestPiece)(Rand.Next(1, sizeof(EnumChestPiece) + 1))` and `var firstPiece = getRandomChessPiece();`

Comment: @Jacob Good idea! I incorporated it as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the random number generated by `Rand` to each of your `int`s and then using those variables. You're not assigning the function of generating the random number. `Rand.Next()` has to be called each time to get a new random number. Also, for best performance, you should create an instance of `Random` use that to generate the random numbers:

```
Random myRandom = new Random();

EnumChestPiece firstPiece = (EnumChestPiece) myRandom.Next(1, sizeof (EnumChestPiece) + 1);
EnumChestPiece secondPiece = (EnumChestPiece) myRandom.Next(1, sizeof (EnumChestPiece) + 1);
EnumChestPiece thirdPiece = (EnumChestPiece) myRandom.Next(1, sizeof (EnumChestPiece) + 1);

EnumColor firstColor = (EnumColor) myRandom.Next(1, sizeof (EnumColor) + 1);
EnumColor secondColor = (EnumColor) myRandom.Next(1, sizeof (EnumColor) + 1);
EnumColor thirdColor = (EnumColor) myRandom.Next(1, sizeof (EnumColor) + 1);
```

Also remember that the random number are only pseudo-random; meaning that they will not be truly random, but in most cases they should be random enough.

Also see the [MSDN article on Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that you may want to consider:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var pieces =
    from p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumChestPiece)).Cast<EnumChestPiece>()
    from c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumColor)).Cast<EnumColor>()
    orderby rnd.Next()
    select new
    {
        Piece = p,
        Color = c,
    };

foreach (var p in pieces.Take(3))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p.Color, p.Piece);
}
```

The advantage to this approach is that it ensures that you don't get duplicate pieces.